# How can I update the toolbar when scrolling with CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to move from one `TextView` to the `Toolbar` when it collapse when scrolling.

Let's say I have a Toolbar and just below of it I have a View, when I scroll up and it starts to not be visible at all I want to update the toolbar with this text, here's an example.

First Scenario
[image]

Second Scenario
[image]

I've been reading with the `CollapsingToolbar` but I can figure it out when the view is not that visible and if I have to create like a custom Toolbar with a text at the right where I can set, because it's not the title, it's an extra value of the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where I can set, because it's not the title, it's an extra value of the title.

You can use the title for a customized `Toolbar` as `supportActionBar`; but adjust the scrolling flags appropriately to the toolbar & the layout behaviour to the main layout.

> if I have to create like a custom Toolbar with a text at the right

To set the title to the right; there are 2 properties, one for the collapsed text, and the other for the expanded, you need to align them to the end/right:

```
app:collapsedTitleGravity="end"
app:expandedTitleGravity="end"
```

Here is a demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="end"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="end"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Hi">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="Hi"
                app:titleTextColor="#fff" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <!--    Main Layout -->

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbarlayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/long_text" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Make sure to use a NoActionBar theme, and set the custom Toolbar as the `supportActionBar`:

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

[image]

**Update:**

> perhaps I missexplained the issue, the thing is, I have a Toolbar and
> just below, I have like a LinearLayout with Text, and when I scroll
> and this LinearLayout is going to hide I want to show the text it was
> in the LinearLayout.  So the idea is, Something like you did, but
> instead of having this "Hi" in the Toolbar, have it in a view just
> below the Toolbar and when I scroll and it starts to get invisible /
> non readable just put this "Hi" text in the Toolbar.

You can do this with a customized `TextView` & the title of the `CollapsingToolBar`.. and programmatically toggle the visibility on both with the `OnOffsetChangedListener`

First, create the below styles fol collapsed & expanded states:

```
    <style name="Title.Collapsed" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Title.Expanded" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    </style>
```

These styles will be applied to `app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance` & `app:expandedTitleTextAppearance` on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` respectively.

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="end"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Title.Collapsed"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="end"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Title.Expanded"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hi"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarlayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/long_text" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The detect the appBarLayout scrolling change in `addOnOffsetChangedListener`:

```
val collapsingToolbar = findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.collapsingToolbar)
collapsingToolbar.title = ""
title = ""

val appBarLayout = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.appBarLayout)
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object : OnOffsetChangedListener {
    var isShow = false
    var scrollRange = -1
    override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout, verticalOffset: Int) {
        if (scrollRange == -1) {
            scrollRange = appBarLayout.totalScrollRange
        }
        if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
            //when collapsingToolbar at that time display actionbar title
            collapsingToolbar.title = "Hi"
            isShow = true
        } else if (isShow) {
            collapsingToolbar.title = ""
            isShow = false
        }
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Zain, but perhaps I missexplained the issue, the thing is, I have a Toolbar and just below, I have like a LinearLayout with Text, and when I scroll and this LinearLayout is going to hide I want to show the text it was in the LinearLayout.

Comment: So the idea is, Something like you did, but instead of having this "Hi" in the Toolbar, have it in a view just below the Toolbar and when I scroll and it starts to get invisible / non readable just put this "Hi" text in the Toolbar.

Comment: I've updated the question... let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: Let me think about it

Comment: But it doesn't mean that have to come from the left to the right, the text can be at the right and then appear in the right of the Toolbar.

Comment: @StuartDTO [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/4DGx0NQ1iMwGJkgoz0/giphy.gif) is what I got so far; the white area of the `hi` text is a `TextView`.. not sure if that what you need

Comment: I solved it creating a LinearLayout and adding a scrollViewListener and checking if the item is visible, what you did?

Comment: It's just a `TextView` within `CoordinatorLayout`  & `CollapsingToolbar`, nothing done programmatically

Comment: Could you post the code please?

Comment: I mean the code of your gif you created

Comment: Accept my apologizes as I was working on something else of `collapsingToolbar` and in yours I really did something programmatically with `OnOffsetChangedListener` to adjust .. I just updated the answer .. hopefully it helps

Comment: I've implemented your solution but I have a problem now... I can not add a sticky button because the NestesScrollView is match_parent, how can I adapt your layout yo have a sticky button at the bottom of the screen? I've tried to add marginBottom to the NestesScrollView then the Sticky button is ok because it doesn't overlap the scroll text but then the collapsing doesn't work... any idea?

Comment: In case you want a question to answer, here it is : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451856/coordinatorlayout-with-nestedscrollview-adding-padding-bottom-for-sticky-button

Comment: Sure pls let me check it today